# How to write a Web Service for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, google-app-engine, soap

I am really new to Python and I have been looking for an example on how to write a  Web Service (XML - SOAP) in Python with Google App Engine with no luck.

Can anyone point me to an article or give me an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was curious about this myself and not finding anything I decided to try to get something to work. The short answer is that it turns out a SOAP service can actually be done using the latest alpha [ZSI library](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html). However it isn't simple and I didn't do much more than a simple request so it could fall apart with a complex type. I'll try to find time to write a tutorial on how to do it and edit this answer with more detail.

Unless this is a hard requirement I would do what jamtoday says and go with a REST or RPC service. The SOAP way could be filled with trouble.

Update: For anyone interested I've written a [tutorial on how to deploy a SOAP service to the Google App Engine](http://www.ioncannon.net/web-services/180/soap-on-the-google-app-engine-platform/). It is long process so I'm just linking to it instead of pasting it all here.

Comment: 8 years later and am facing a related problem but in java not python, please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573829/how-to-send-and-receive-soap-data-from-webservice-to-google-app-engine

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something with App Engine specifically, there are libraries that will make it much faster on your end. I'd recommend looking at the XML-RPC and REST examples.

http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/xml-rpc-server-using-google-app-engine/

http://github.com/fczuardi/gae-rest/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but just in case if someone happens to read this.
I have just start an open source project for creating web services on GAE.

Project site: http://code.google.com/p/webserviceservlet/

Hope this is helpful.

EDIT: 
Just noticed that this is a python question and the link project is java project....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Python Web Services](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/) project that might be helpful.

**EDIT**

And here is a [SOAP consuming demonstration](http://diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/)....

Comment: Actually that search won't give you any helpful examples. From all accounts it probably just can't be done.

Comment: There is no examples and the Python Web Services seems to be dead.

Comment: Just put in another link to code examples.

Comment: The question is not about how to consume a Web Service in Python, but how to write one.

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at the [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) framework. It's a Python framework which with you can easily create a REST api.
In my opinion, REST is definitely better than SOAP. It can be easily consumed by any software able to speak http, and it's faster to implement.