# App Engine Datastore access

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to query App Engine's Datastore from outside the cloud, i.e. a client application?

I could possibly write an app to be housed within AppStore and query the Datastore returning XML-formatted data; I want to know, however, if there are any Datastore endpoints which would allow me to do it directly.

Also, in case it *is* possible, am I able to do so via SSL?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331600/how-to-write-a-web-service-for-google-app-engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The [remote_api library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) supports exactly this use-case. If you're using Java, there's a Java remote_api handler available, and the client will be available at some point in the future.

You can use this over SSL in the same way as any other handler.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I guess your answer most closely resembles what I expected. Yet, let me make sure I am getting things right: this is a module which I "install", and which provides a RESTful endpoint for other applications to directly query the Datastore, right? (meaning there are no "out-of-the-box" interfaces for directly querying the Datastore from outside the cloud)

Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: It's a module you install, but it's not really 'restful', and it's intended only for administrative access - anyone who can use remote_api basically has complete control over your app's data. And it's about as out of the box as it comes - it's part of the SDK, you just need to install a handler to use it.

Comment: Can anyone please elaborate on why this should only be used for administrative access?

Comment: @Nilzor Isn't the fact that anyone who has access to it has complete control over your app's datastore sufficient?

Comment: That is an argument for why you shouldn't put it in a client application. What if I create an intermediate service (not on GAE) which uses the library to store data?

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason you couldn't create your own app engine application that exposes the datastore as a web service (either http or https). In fact, here is a [link](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/) to a python version.

Comment: Thanks, Taylor - yet, in case I do not want to write a module myself, I believe Nick's answer more closely resembles what I was searching for - it's already written!