# Transfer Data From App to App?

Tags: ios, networking, data-transfer

Heres my plan. Two people have my app and I need to get a bunch of data from one to the other.

The person receiving the data doesn't know that they might be sent something, they two people could be in completely different places in the world, so it can't be transferred locally.

So, our of maybe thousands of people who use the app, I could have it, host a bunch of data and then only my specified receivers could then get that data from me and have it in their app.

I am VERY new to server/network stuff, so as much detail in your responses would be hugely helpful.

Any help or tips on how to do this would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a classic client server.

Setup a server. 
Have app from user A send data to server. 
Send push notification to us B he has new data. 
When user B open the app have him poll the server for his new information.

Comment: Client side? So the person sending the info hosts the data in the app and then the other person grabs it from them directly? I don't have any server experience, if you could give a little more detail or poke me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: The app is always the client. They reach out to the server to either put information on it or pull information from it. The server hosts the data most likely in database like SQL or the like. You can see a very basic example of client server on iOS with PHP here. But you'll need to do a bit more work on the server side to store the data and let your app query for it ( connecting to database, inserting and pulling )

Comment: Ok, this isn't quite clicking with me, sorry. So you have `iPhone 1` sends data to `server` (what kind of server is this, where is it hosted?) and then `iPhone 2` grabs data from server.

Comment: Another important factor (which Im unsure how to deal with) is that when `iPhone 2` grabs data, it needs to be the data from `iPhone 1` and not from anyone else's data.

Comment: Regarding your last comment - that's completely possible - just implement whatever logic you need on the server side. Regarding kind of server and where to host - I think the Google App Engine would be the place for you to start with if you don't have other server experience. Read this question and all it's answers and links - should help you get started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331600/how-to-write-a-web-service-for-google-app-engine

Answer (score -1):

Store the data in an online database.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote seeing as I was saying the same as the answer below. ho hum. I guess brevity isn't good round here, lol.