# Web Service from Google App Engine/ Google Web Tool kit?

Tags: java, wcf, google-app-engine, gwt

I am a total beginner to web programming.

I'd like to create a web service using GAE/GWT with Java which functions similarly to how WCF from the .NET platform works. Is this possible?

I've been researching for a while and there are no really good solid examples. If someone could point me to good reading or examples then I'd be happy to take a look.

I checked this out : [How to write a Web Service for Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331600/how-to-write-a-web-service-for-google-app-engine?rq=1)

However, that is python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to read the [tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html) at the GWT official site. The StockWatcher example teaches how to write an application, and discusses the different ways to retrieve information from the server. It works in either GAE or any other servlet container, it has even an example about how to create the web service in a php and consume it.

The left index of the tutorial is not correctly sorted because the gwtproject.org site documentation is produced automatically, but clicking on the next step link in each page you go to the next one.

[EDITED]
Index of the GWT project is now correctly sorted after my [changes](https://plus.google.com/107827577469812856793/posts/FzJ6jGHThAp)